# How to figure out the max value for capacity parameter passed to Dictionary constructor to avoid OutOfMemoryException?

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, out-of-memory

Related to this:

[System.OutOfMemoryException because of Large Dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5336011/system-outofmemoryexception-because-of-large-dictionary)

I am getting `OutOfMemoryException` when I let .NET manage my dictionary. The exception thrown in resize method. So I was trying to avoid resizing by providing large number as a capacity. Naturally I tried to start from `int.MaxValue` just to make sure it will help to solve the problem. I was planning to go down as much as needed.

However `OutOfMemoryException` is thrown for `int.MaxValue`. I decided to make a little binary search and the very first value for capacity that was accepted by constructor turned to be `int.MaxValue / 32`. Not only that is smaller than I have expected but it is also just confusing.

So has anyone have any ideas why?

Oh, the project settings are setup to use x64 architecture.

Comment: In 64-bit .NET prior to .NET 4.5, the maximum number of items in a dictionary (using a reference for a key and a reference for the value) is 89,478,457. That's an experimentally derived result. See [my blog entry](http://blog.mischel.com/2008/05/21/more-on-net-collection-sizes/) and linked articles.

Comment: @Jim `int.MaxValue / 24 = 89478485.3333...`, just 32 1/3 higher than your value.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The hard limit for `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` is due to the private field `entries`, which has the type `Entry[]`. In this case `Entry` is a struct:

```
private struct Entry {
  public int hashCode;
  public int next;
  public TKey key;
  public TValue value;
}
```

The minimum size of `Entry` is 4*4, which could happen if `TKey` and `TValue` are both 4-byte types (referring to the array alignment size, i.e. the value returned by [the CLI `sizeof` bytecode instruction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.sizeof.aspx)). This results in a limit of `int.MaxValue / (2*16)` entries due to the [array size limitation in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338778/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-an-array-in-net-on-64-bit-windows). If you use a `TKey` or `TValue` type which is larger than 4 bytes, the maximum dictionary size would decrease accordingly.

For large dictionaries like you are suggesting, a [B+-tree implementation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%2B_tree) of [`IDictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4ys34ea.aspx) would be a more efficient use of system resources and would not be subject to the array size limitation.

Comment: I guess they used a struct to make it faster. If they'd used a class, then the limit would be a lot higher.

Comment: @MatthewWatson It's a general purpose type. Item count > 67,108,863 doesn't sound like general purpose use to me.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Which is obviously the wise trade-off to make for the most frequently used implementation of `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>`. This is also the reason why none of the methods in `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` are virtual. :)

Comment: Absolutely! I certainly wasn't suggesting that it was a mistake!

Comment: @280Z28 This makes a lot of sense and is supported by my observation. I have actually ~73M records to handle. Key is ULONG and value is 4x1byte. While I was waiting for the answer, I was able to make things barely work with `int.MaxValue/28`.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to 280Z28's answer:

If you really must have such a large dictionary, AND you are running on x64, AND you are using .Net 4.5 or later, then you can enable large object support. That will allow a much larger dictionary.

In my tests, I could specify a capacity up to `int.MaxValue/2`

To do so, add to your "app.config" file a section as follows:

```
<runtime>
  <gcAllowVeryLargeObjects enabled="true" />
</runtime>
```

So your entire "app.config" file might look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
  <runtime>
    <gcAllowVeryLargeObjects enabled="true" />
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

See here for more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh285054.aspx